# Откат версии Asterisk

Tags: linux, asterisk

Нужна чистая 11 версия для полной совместимости с chan_dongle, случайно сделал yum update и теперь asterisk версии 11.2, не знаю как откатить обратно, гугл не помог, хочет что бы я версию ОС откатил, а не одного приложения.

Сборка FreePBX Distro на CentOS 6.5

[Download FreePBX Distro](https://www.freepbx.org/downloads/)

Версия STABLE – 6.12.65 на 2015 год, почему говорите, что древняя?

Comment: укажите, пожалуйста, название и версию используемого вами дистрибутива операционной системы gnu/linux.

Comment: впрочем, судя по всему, вам надо собирать столь древнюю версию самостоятельно. исходники старых версий можно взять отсюда: http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/old-releases/

Comment: Исправил ^^ посмотрите.

Comment: посмотрите, когда [выпущена версия 11](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk). это было очень давно. сейчас из **этой ветки** [актуальны уже версии с 11.16 по 11.21](http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/). собранные пакеты для версии 11.0.0 давно удалены с серверов asterisk-а, и даже исходники уже давно ушли в архив (ссылку я дал выше).